# How to get array of an specific attribute values from a list of custom object

Tags: java, java-7

I have a `List<MyClass>` and there is an attribute named **attribute1** in `MyClass`.

Now the question is, how i can get the **attribute1** values from `List<MyClass>` as an array without looping through the list in traditional way?

Comment: How do you think it should work without a loop?

Comment: MayBe through reflection aur some Utility class can do the trick

Comment: @AhsanShah and how does the Utility class do the trick?

Comment: In Java 8 it will be possible. :)

Comment: @kocko Will it though?

Comment: Welcome Jon, i love see some solution from you man... my guru

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I think so. With map/reduce and lambdas. :)

Comment: I believe kocko is in right direction

Comment: @kocko And what will that do in the background?

Comment: Looping, I believe. But it will reduce the code we write, at least. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Guava's FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) to collect your elements, here's an example assuming  `attribute1` is an Integer

```
    //populated
    List<MyClass> yourList;

    List<Integer> listbyAttribute = FluentIterable.from(yourList)
            .transform(new Function<MyClass, Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(MyClass f) {
            return f.getAttribute1();
        }
    }).toList();
```

More fun with this Guava class: [here](http://blog.wsoczynski.pl/en/2013/03/16/english-google-guava-one-class-to-ruleem-all-fluentiterable/)

Comment: _Suggest some solution without loop or iteration._

Comment: That's impossible I guess, as you pointed out. But this is an alternative to traditional iteration and maybe would help him.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class which implements LIST interface. YOu should basically do the implementation which is exactly the same as one of the other implementation of list except;

1)you in your add method, every time you add a new element, append it in a string array which   is a variable of your class.

2)and add an extra method, lets say giveMyAttribute1List and return the variable list I mentioned earlier.

you you basically have your answer.

```
List<MyClass> a = new myListIMpl<MyClass>();
a.giveMyAttribute1List();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is some kind of tricky question where you (yourself) are not allowed to use a *for-each*, an *iterator* nor an old fashioned *for-loop* (like being asked in a job interview), I would suggest using the following:

```
Collections.sort(myList, myComparator)
```

and create the comparator

```
public class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final MyClass o1, final MyClass o2) {
      // implement
    }
}
```

and implement the `compare` method in such a way, that the **attribute1** is either in front (or back, or somewhere you know). Then you can easily fetch the element from the list without manually looping through it.
But this answer applies only if this is some kind of "job interview question", otherwise looping through the list is most likely the only option you have.

Comment: it is not a interview question and your solution tooo complex and sure it will work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of an attribute of each element in a `List`, you have to visit each element of that `List`. In other words, you have to iterate over each element. Whether you visit the elements in order with a loop or randomly in some ridiculous way, you're looping/iterating.

What you are asking for is not possible.